# Image of dimension 2560*1600 px is covering the entire page when width is set to 100%

Tags: html, css, image

I want the image to cover the entire width, i.e 100%, but height only 40%.

For this I make a CSS class for `img` tag and specify `width: 100%` and `height: 40%`. It covers the entire page and shows only a part of it.

Comment: provide a working fiddle..

Comment: is this for body? or a div?

Comment: Image is not displayed here

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/e2uaU/

Comment: @user3291616 there is no img in your fiddle !!!

Comment: @user3291616 I've just added a better solution,  Check it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly your problem, but i guess this simple code may help you,

If your talking about an `img` in a `div` try this

```
<div style="height: 500px; width: 500px; background: #555;">
    <img src="http://www.weidert.com/Portals/65360/images/google-logo.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 40%">
</div>
```

But if you are talking about an `img` in the `body` try this

```
<body style=" background: #555; height: 100%;">
    <img src="http://www.weidert.com/Portals/65360/images/google-logo.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 40%">
</body>
```

Hope this will help you ...

---

### Update:

To update the height after changing the orientation of the device try to add this code to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
        $( "body" ).css("height", $(window).outerHeight(false)+"px");
    }, false);
</script>
```

So it will be like this simple code:

```
<body style=" background: #555; height: 100%;">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
            $( "body" ).css("height", $(window).outerHeight(false)+"px");
        }, false);
    </script>
    <img src="http://www.weidert.com/Portals/65360/images/google-logo.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 40%">
</body>
```

---

### Another solution (Better)

you can let the **JavaScript** set the `height` of the image so it will be like this :

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setImageHeight();
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
            setImageHeight();
        });
        function setImageHeight(){
            $( ".mainImage" ).css({
                "height": $(window).outerHeight(false)*0.40+"px",
                "width": "100%"
            });
        }
    </script>
    <img class="mainImage" src="http://www.weidert.com/Portals/65360/images/google-logo.jpg">
</body>
```

notice that you don't need to add any style to `body`, you just need to add the **JavaScript** code.

Comment: Actually i am making a mobile app, so did not want to use px because it gives distorted results when used for tab (if coded for phone). I thought to use % instead so that what ever the screen size is it adjusts accordingly. I want a an image (2500px*1600px) to stretch 100% width and only 40% height so that i can write text paragraphs below it.

Comment: I changed the size of the div to height=:250px width:1024px, the image gets shrinked but ok works yet when i tilt the tab back to potrait mode the image gets cut and full image is not shown

Comment: @user3291616 I've updated my answer, take a look at it ..